# Charles Proxy "Couldn't find certificate file"

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to install Charles root certificate on my machine. When I click the "Install Charles root certificate", instead of opening keychain and install the certificate, it gives error dialog "Couldn't find certificate file".

I also tried exporting the file, but got same dialog.

Someone mentioned it should be Charles' local config/cache got messed up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community no error dialog should happen